# Refactoring repeated range checks which use if statements

Tags: c++, c++11, if-statement, conditional-statements

Below I attach code, with logical statements. By looking at this code I can see its very repetitive.

My task: 9x9 grid is given to me with 9 boxes inside, I am trying to get the indexes to start the loop from (`startRow/Col`) to (`startRow/Col+2`).

```
vector<int> findBox(int row, int col){
    int startRow;
    int startCol;
    if(row <= 2){
        startRow = 0;
    } else if(row > 2 && row <= 5){
        startRow = 3;
    } else if(row > 5 && row <= 8){
        startRow = 6;
    }
    if(col <= 2){
        startCol = 0;
    } else if (col > 2 && col <= 5){
        startCol = 3;
    } else if(col > 5 && col <= 8){
        startCol = 6;
    }
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(startRow);
    v.push_back(startCol);
    return v;
}
```

I am looking for someone to explain me the better way. Or should I just try to refactor the code and use switch?

Thank you.

Jak

Comment: I'm not sure I understand -- you're given the row and column that a series of 9 contiguous cels in a 9x9 array needs to start at? Can you restate the problem you're trying to solve, and why you're using a vector to return the two values?

Answer (score 3):

No need to use a switch. Take advantage of integer division which will discard the remainder:

```
int startRow{row / 3 * 3};
int startCol{col / 3 * 3};
```

The function then becomes:

```
vector<int> findBox(int row, int col){
    int startRow{row / 3 * 3};
    int startCol{col / 3 * 3};
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(startRow);
    v.push_back(startCol);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for quick reply.

I will edit and use this formula for my calculations.

Comment: Upvote: nice to see someone not dicking about with unnecessary parentheses. Also good reliance on NRVO.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
vector<int> findBox (int row, int col)
 { return { (row - row % 3), (col - col % 3) }; }
```

?

Comment: Which reminds us that if all you want to do is return 2 values, then use std::pair